# Load grails action in jQuery-Tabs via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, tabs, gsp

I'm using the Tabs from jQuery UI in my Grails application. 
In the different tabs, I want to display actions from a controller (so no static html site or so).

```
<script>
    $(function() {$("#tabs").tabs()
</script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <g:include controller="controller1" action="action1" />
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <g:include controller="controller2" action="action2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to load these actions, or a gsp-site via AJAX?

There is an example on the jQuery-Website (http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax), but in this example they load just a static html site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your tab content to load dynamically when switching tabs, the Grails approach looks very similar to the jQuery-UI example.  Just substitute `createLink()` for the .php links.  Also, you were missing a closing brace & paren on your JavaScript init function (though this may have just been lost during copy/paste):

```
<script>
    $(function() { $("#tabs").tabs() });
</script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="${createLink(controller: 'controller2', action: 'action2')}">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="${createLink(controller: 'controller3', action: 'action3')}">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Render content for first tab on initial page load, could also do this via jQuery -->
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <g:include controller="controller1" action="action1" />
    </div>
    <!-- divs for other tabs' content will be created automatically -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!
It also works with:
<li><g:remoteLink controller="controller1" action="action1">TouchPoint Master</g:remoteLink></li>

but I suppose, that's doing the same as createLink()...

Comment: Using `remoteLink` in the tab ul/li links will cause the load to occur twice: once by jQuery UI, and once by the JavaScript generated by the `remoteLink` tag.  I recommend sticking with `createLink` which creates a plain URL
, without any extra AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You haven't mentioned what event will trigger the AJAX request that loads the content. If for example, the content is loaded when the user clicks on a link, you can acheive this by replacing this:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <g:include controller="controller1" action="action1" />
</div>
```

with this:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <g:remoteLink controller="controller1" action="action1" update="tabs-1">click to load</g:remoteLink>
</div>
```

If it's some other event, then you'll probably want to use [g.remoteFunction](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
         $("#tabs").tabs()
         jQuery("a[href=#tabs-2]").click(function() {
                ${remoteFunction(action: 'test1',update: [success: 'tabs-2'])}
         });
         jQuery("a[href=#tabs-1]").click(function() {
                ${remoteFunction(action: 'test2',update: [success: 'tabs-1'])}
         });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
    </div>
</div>
```